# Word table extraction to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I want to extract a table from a Word document and put the data into a dictionary.  Column 2 contains a single value and column 4 has multiple values.  Ideally, I want it to look like this:

```
{category: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']}
```

I can run each column separately and gather all of the contents without any problems but when I try to run it and put them into a dictionary, I lose values from column 4:

```
{category: ['test1', 'test2', 'test4']}
```

Here's the code I run:

```
from docx import Document
document = Document('V2.11.0_practice.docx')
tables = document.tables
unitTest = {}
for row in tables[0].rows:
    unitTest[row.cells[1].paragraphs[0].text] = []
    for paragraph in row.cells[3].paragraphs:
        unitTest[row.cells[1].paragraphs[0].text].append(paragraph.text.lower())
print(unitTest)

category = []
for row in tables[0].rows:
    category.append(row.cells[1].paragraphs[0].text)
print(category)

test = []
for row in tables[0].rows:
    for paragraph in row.cells[3].paragraphs:
        test.append(paragraph.text.lower())
print(test)
```

printing category correctly shows all the categories.  printing test correctly shows all the tests.  however, printing unitTest shows some but not all of the tests.  unitTest doesn't collect all of the tests for each category in the Word table.

Comment: Can you also show the code that you say works without problems? I don't quite understand what the difference is supposed to be.

Comment: @mkrieger1 please see my edits

Comment: Maybe `row.cells[1].paragraphs[0].text` is not unique for each row?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it is unique for each row and each paragraph